# How Chrome added text to tab switcher in a drawable?

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, android-studio

I am building an android web browser and I just wish to know how chrome added text(numbers) to the tab switching button?

Here's an image:

[image: Google image]

Is it simple text wrapped in a drawable? If yes, then how to do that and increment the number when a new tab is opened?

If no, then what's the way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi Gourav, if one of the answers helped you, please kindly accept it as an answer.

Comment: First let me try them! most probably your answer is correct!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the layout boundaries(enabled from Developers Option), It is a custom view or drawable.

[image]

This kind of views or drawables are made to serve special purpose and to have control over your layout. But there are also much more time consuming to make, most of the times.

[This](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view) is a good starting point for custom views. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IFS1mG5UsU) video taught me a lot in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a TextView. Background of the TextView is a custom drawable(xml).

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="12"
    android:background="@drawable/my_text_drawable"/>
```

Sample `my_text_drawable.xml` is like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke android:color="#999999" android:width="2dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
</shape>
```